# The right way to compare Long type in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a MongoDB collection with the data like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61374ec2d53afa0368df9a39"
  },
  "UUID": "3c113734-4249-448b-96bc-b20ddd5aa7d0",
  "StartTime": {
    "$numberLong": "1631014594147"
  },
  "ExpireDate": {
    "$numberLong": "1646566594149"
  },
  "status": "TERMINATED"
}
```

Trying to aggregate data matching **StartDate** to some timestamp

```
{
    $match: {
      StartTime: {
        $gte: 1689206400000,
      },
    },
  }
```

This working well.

```
{
    $match: {
      StartTime: {
        $gte: {
          $toLong: "1689206400000",
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

But this - does not want to work, despite the fact that both are Long type

Finally, as a result, I want to get a list of documents that are created today, for example satisfying the following condition

```
{
    $match: {
      StartTime: {
        $gte: {
          $toLong: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: {
                $substr: [
                  {
                    $toString: "$$NOW",
                  },
                  0,
                  10,
                ],
              },
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: You need to use `$expr` to access aggregation expression operators (such as `$roLong`) inside of a `$match` stage. From [the top of the `$match` docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) directly: "_Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in 
$match._"

Comment: Tried. Yes, the search is happening. But somehow wrong
Query
`{$match: { $expr: { $gte: [ "StartTime", { $toLong: { $dateFromString: { dateString: { $substr: [{$toString: "$$NOW"}, 0, 10 ] } 
 format: "%Y-%m-%d" }}}}]}}}`
The query found such values as 1631014594147, 1631015330163, despite the fact that today it is 1689206400000 
May be I made a mistake/ If you have the solution please share

Comment: `"StartTime"` is incorrect. Should be `"$StartTime"` inside of expressions. As currently written it's just comparing against the literal string. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gEvoOFQOAqM)